# Serial COM port works only in debug

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port, race-condition

I have a race condition or something like it. I mean if I toggle a breakpoint before reading from COM, everything is good. But when i'm toggling it off, it freezes. writing:

```
    public void Send(ComMessage message)
    {
        byte[] bytes = message.Serialise();
        if (!_outputPort.IsOpen)
            _outputPort.Open();
        try
        {
            byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length);
            _outputPort.Write(size, 0, size.Length);
            _outputPort.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_outputPort != _inputPort)
                _outputPort.Close();
        }
    }
```

reading

```
    private void InputPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        var port = (SerialPort) sender;

        byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[sizeof(long)];
        port.Read(sizeBuffer, 0, sizeBuffer.Length);
        int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBuffer, 0);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

        int i = 0;
        while (i < length)
        {
            int readed = port.Read(buffer, i, length - i);
            i += readed;
        }


        var message = ComMessage.Deserialize(buffer);
        MessageReceived(this, message);
    }
```

for example, message has 625 bytes length. If I toggle a breakpoint, `port.BytesToRead` is equal 625, but if I disable it, byte count is 621.

Strange, but it works for a little amount of bytes (for short messages), but doesn't for long.

Please, advice.

Comment: Read does not guarantee you read `sizeBuffer.Length` bytes. You need to get the int returned from from Read and use that. You are not guaranteed what was sent on one side will be received as one message on the other side.

Comment: Your Send() method is badly broken, closing the port discards the content of the transmit buffer.  It works when you debug because you give the driver enough time to empty the buffer before you close the port.  There's more trouble with Close(), read the MSDN article.  Boilerplate is to only ever call Open() at program initialization and not Close() until it ends.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I edited, but this version doesn't work properly too

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I'l try it. Because I thinked I should interact with it like with db connection - open and close only when transmitting the data

Comment: For your updated version you still never check the first `Read` to see how many bytes it read. It may have read less than `sizeof(long)` bytes in. Also you are making a buffer of size `long` but long is `Int64`, you are calling `ToInt32`. You should be either doing `sizeof(int)` or even better to make it more obvious `sizeof(Int32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> message has 625 bytes length. If I toggle a breakpoint,
>   port.BytesToRead is equal 625, but if I disable it, byte count is 621.

You never check the first `Read` to see how many bytes it read. It may have read less than `sizeof(long)` bytes in. However, that is not the source of your problem, your main problem is you are making a buffer of size `long` but long is `Int64`, you are calling `ToInt32` (and writing a `Int32` in your sender).

The reason your byte count is 261 instead of 265 is because the first 4 bytes of your message is sitting in `sizeBuffer[4]` through `sizeBuffer[7]` which you never processed.

To fix this you should be either doing `sizeof(int)` or even better to make it more obvious that the buffer is for the `ToInt32` call, use `sizeof(Int32)`